# Nginx Caching 301 Response

Tags: http, nginx, caching, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a nginx reverse proxy that forwards all requests to a server that then redirects (301) to an aws service. The requests returns pdb files that can be pretty big and normally the same request might be called multiple time so caching the response would be good.

My problem is that it seems that instead of caching the "file", it seems to be caching the redirects itself instead of the response because the caching files are nowhere near the size of the real file and the gain in request time is way less than if I try without a redirect.

I want to know if there is a way to avoid this behavior and cache the response everytime.

This is my configuration

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  1;
events {
  worker_connections  10240;
}
http {

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile            on;
  tcp_nopush          on;
  tcp_nodelay         on;
  keepalive_timeout   65;
  types_hash_max_size 4096;

  include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;

  proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx keys_zone=one:10m use_temp_path=off;
  server {
      listen       80;
      listen       [::]:80;
      server_name  _;
      root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

      # Load configuration files for the default server block.
      include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://server.org/;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_cache one;
      proxy_http_version     1.1;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      proxy_cache_key $scheme$request_uri;
      proxy_cache_valid any 24h;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Caching the redirection is the expected behavior because the target may change, and because the server has no copy of the target content when returning the redirection. It has only a copy of the redirection, but not the actual content.

So, you firstly need to let nginx follow the redirection:

https://serverfault.com/questions/423265/how-to-follow-http-redirects-inside-nginx

or

https://gist.github.com/JonasGao/89370dc9cf84f4bbc1131fce2e700635
.

Or, you may want the upstream server to return the contents instead of redirections. Since you have the control over the upstream server, I think this is the better option.